# Retrieve current UserId and insert into table?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using the following code, a user inputs a date into a textbox control and then clicks a button. A new record is created in table [rms_Report] and then I retrieve the ID of the record that was just added. I pass this ID onto page "CreateReport.aspx" via a response.redirect and query string.

I need to retrieve the UserId of the currently logged in user and insert it into table [rms_Report]. I need this to occur after the new record is inserted, but obviously before the response.redirect. I know how to retrieve the UserId, but I'm not sure how to incorporate into the other code. Can anyone provide some insight?

**ASPX**

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ReportDataSource" runat="server" 
        OnInserted="ReportDataSource_Inserted"
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"  
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [rms_Report] ([ReportDate]) VALUES (@ReportDate) SELECT @NewReportID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ReportDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="NewReportID" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**ASPX.VB**

```
Protected Sub ReportDataSource_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)

    'Read the value of the @NewProductID OUTPUT parameter
    Dim newReportID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters("@NewReportID").Value)

    Response.Redirect("CreateReport.aspx?ReportID=" & newReportID)

End Sub
```

**UPDATED ASPX**

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ReportDataSource" runat="server"
        OnInserted="ReportDataSource_Inserted"
        OnInserting="ReportDataSource_Inserting"
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"  
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [rms_Report] ([UserID], [ReportDate]) VALUES (@UserID, @ReportDate) SELECT @NewReportID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ReportDate" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" Name="UserID" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="NewReportID" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**UPDATED ASPX.VB**

```
   Protected Sub ReportDataSource_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)

        Dim newReportID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters("@NewReportID").Value)

        Response.Redirect("CreateReport.aspx?ReportID=" & newReportID)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub ReportDataSource_Inserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs)

        Dim currentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
        Dim currentUserId As Guid = CType(currentUser.ProviderUserKey, Guid)
        e.Command.Parameters("@UserID").Value = currentUserId

    End Sub
```

Comment: By 'insert into table [rms_report]', do you mean UPDATE the [rms_report] record you just created with the current user's id? If so, is there a reason you don't pass the userid into the first insert statement itself (reportDate and UserId both)?

Comment: See my answer about overriding the OnInserting event of the SqlDataSource to modify the parameter value.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Asp.net," and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ReportDataSource" runat="server" 
        OnInserted="ReportDataSource_Inserted"
        OnInserting="ReportDataSource_Inserting"
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"  
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [rms_Report] ([ReportDate]) VALUES (@ReportDate) SELECT @NewReportID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ReportDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="NewReportID" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In the code-behind, you can then change the value of the parameter before the command is actually run against the database by using the OnInserting event.

```
Protected Sub ReportDataSource_Inserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs)
    e.Command.Parameters["@Userid"].Value = YourUserIdValue
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! With a couple of modifications, your code worked. I placed the modified (working) code in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code

```
dim loggedinuser as string = CStr(Page.User.Identity.Name).Split("\")(1)
```